# Tween to appear like zoom in and out-LibGdx

Tags: libgdx

In game menu,I placed one part of title and I want to make it moving from left to right.

I did it like this:

```
private final MutableFloat text1 = new MutableFloat(0);
```

All these should happen once when menu screens just launches.

```
    private final TweenManager tweenManager = new TweenManager();
```

inside class constructor:

```
Tween.to(text1 , 3, 0.5f).target(Constants.WORLD_HEIGHT-300).ease(Back.IN).start(tweenManager);
```

It works.Now I want to give other part of the title something like zoom in and out effect using tween.(May be possible with scale)
Which tween to use and how can I implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using mutable float was creating issues.
This worked for me:

```
Timeline.createSequence().delay(0.8f)
            .push(Tween.to(titleImage2, ActorAccessor.SCALE_XY, 
  0.5f).target(0.5f, 0.5f)).pushPause(0.5f)
            .push(Tween.to(titleImage2, ActorAccessor.SCALE_XY, 1).target(1, 
    1)).start(tweenManager);
```